# issue about embed window to external process using setparent(win32 api)

Tags: user-interface, winapi, setparent

I'm just trying to embed a window from my process into the window of an external process using the SetParent function, but I find out the application can't switch back after minimizing.

The embedded window is WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW style, changing it to WS_CHILD can handle this issue. But we need WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW for other reasons.

Is anyone can give me a hand of this?

Comment: You are not expected to be able to do this. The functionality only exists for back compat with the 16 bit days.

Comment: See [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683), and maybe also [A window can have a parent or an owner but not both](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100315-00/?p=14613).